# subtitles are not showing in videojs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, video.js, azure-media-services, drm

subtitles are not showing in videojs

I am using video.js in our react.js and typescript project.
for streaming we are using azure media services and DRM for encryption.
video is playing perfectly and also multiple audio is palying fine but the issue we are facing is subtitle is not showing.
here is the code we are using but in this.player.textTracks() function is giving no TextTracks.
its working fine with shaka player and subtitles are showing also its working fine in react native but the player is diffrent and that is not supported for web.

```
import videojs from 'video.js';
import '@videojs/http-streaming';
import "videojs-contrib-eme";
import HlsParser from 'hls-parser';

componentDidMount() {
      this.player = this.initializePlayer();

        // set eme plugin
        this.player.eme();

        // add video resources streaming url etc
        this.setVideoReaource();
        
        this.fetchSubtitles();
    }
    
     initializePlayer = () => {
        return videojs("video", {
            enableSourceset: true,
            preload: "auto",
            fluid: true,
            aspectRatio: '16:9',
            controls: true,
            autoplay: true,
            controlBar: {
                pictureInPictureToggle: false,
                remainingTimeDisplay: false,
                fullscreenToggle: true,
                volumePanel: {
                    inline: false
                },
            },
            html5: {
                nativeTextTracks: true
            }
        });
    }

    setVideoReaource = () => {
        this.player.src({
            src: `https://vodemedia-usea.streaming.media.azure.net/4ac3e64a-aa82-460d-a7f5-06632522aae2/The Bad Guys_2022 New Eng and Ar.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-cmaf,encryption=cenc)`,
            type: 'application/x-mpegURL',
            keySystems: {
                'com.widevine.alpha': this.widevineLicenseURI,
                'com.microsoft.playready': true
            },
        });
    }


    fetchSubtitles() {
        const subtitles = this.player.textTracks();
        console.log('subtitles');
        console.log(subtitles);
        for (const element of subtitles) {
          const subtitle = element;
          if (subtitle.src) {
            this.player.addRemoteTextTrack({
              kind: 'subtitles',
              src: subtitle.src,
              srclang: subtitle.language,
              label: subtitle.label,
              default: true
            });
          }
        }
      }
      
      render() {
        return(
          <div>
             <video
               height="480"
               id="video"
               className={`video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-fill vjs-custom-theme`}
               controls
               data-setup="{}">
             </video>     
          </div>
      }
```

Note:-   also we try to fetch subtitle from manifest url using this code but we are not getting any playlists in manifestObject.

```
fetch(`https://vodemedia-usea.streaming.media.azure.net/4ac3e64a-aa82-460d-a7f5-06632522aae2/The Bad Guys_2022 New Eng and Ar.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-cmaf,encryption=cenc)`)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(manifest => {
                console.log(manifest);
                const manifestObject = HlsParser.parse(manifest);
                console.log('manifestObject');
                console.log(manifestObject);

                   const subtitlePlaylist = manifestObject.playlists.find(playlist => playlist.attributes && playlist.attributes.SUBTITLES);
                   const subtitleTrack = subtitlePlaylist && subtitlePlaylist.mediaGroups.SUBTITLES.en.find(track => track.default);

                    console.log('subtitlePlaylist');
                    console.log(subtitlePlaylist);
                    this.player.addRemoteTextTrack({
                        kind: 'subtitles',
                        src: subtitleTrack.uri,
                        srclang: subtitleTrack.language,
                        label: 'English'
                      });
            })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

please help me if any one have solution on this. and if want to connect one to one please let me know we can connect.